pycapnp: traversing nodes, imported not visible
This question is related to my previous question and Johnny Cheesecutter´s comment. It should clarify what I intended
Currently, we're using JSON for our client/server communication. Now we'd like to switch to Capnp. Our protocol uses about 150 different messages. The client (GUI) does not use the JSON structs directly; on receiption, the JSON data a copied to appropriate objects. When replacing JSON by Capnp, we have to adapt this layer. Thus I thought of generating this layer. Here is an example:
test1.capnp:
...
using Enum2 = import "test2.capnp".Enum2;
using Struct2 = import "test2.capnp".Struct2;

enum Enum1
{
  nil @0;
  one @1;
  two @2;
}

struct Struct11
{
  e1   @0:Enum1;
  e2   @1:Enum2;
}

struct Struct12
{
  s1 @0:Struct11;
  l1 @1:List(Struct2);
}

test2.capnp:
...
enum Enum2
{
  nil @0;
  one @1;
  two @2;
}

struct Struct2
{
  u8   @0:UInt8;
  u16  @1:UInt16;
}

I wrote a small script that generates the following from test1.capnp:
enum _Enum1
{
    NIL = 0,
    ONE = 1,
    TWO = 2
};

// class to int (as we use plain enums so far)
_Enum1 Enum1Convert(
    Enum1 from);

class Struct11
{
public:
    bool Parse(const void *data, int size);
    _Enum1 E1;
    #MISSING# E2;
};

class Struct12
{
public:
    bool Parse(const void *data, int size);
    Struct11 S1;
    std::array<#MISSING#> L1;
};

The corresponding cpp file is also generated, here is a snippet:
bool Struct11::Parse(const void *data, int size)
{
    if (data == nullptr)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Wrapper, not further explained in example here
    CapnpDeserializer deserializer(data, size);
    auto _cp = deserializer.GetReader<Struct11>();

    this->E1 = _cp.getE1();
    this->E2 = _cp.getE2();
    return true;
}

The script basically starts with:
def __init__(self, file: str):
    self.file = file
    self.parser = SchemaParser()
    root = self.parser.load(file)
    self.types = []
    for node in root.schema.node.nestedNodes:
        attr = getattr(root, node.name)
        if isinstance(attr, capnp._StructModule):
            self.types.append(StructType(root, node))
    ...

The __init__() of my helper class StructType is:
def __init__(self, root: object, structNode: object):
    ...
    fields = getattr(root, structNode.name).schema.node.struct.fields
    for field in fields:
        which = field.slot.type.which.__str__()
        if field.slot.type.which == 'enum':
            ### TROUBLE ###

Here I came in trouble with imported Enums:
I can read field.slot.type.enum.typeId, but I could not resolve that typeId, i.e., I found no way to get the details of that Enum (Enum2 in the example above).
Same for Struct2 in the example; I can see the typeId but don't know how to get the fields, as imported types are not part of root.schema.node.nestedNodes
Basically, the question is: Is there any way to get full information about imported nodes (structs, enums) from the data returned by SchemaParser() ?

This isn't really an answer, but I'm working on something similar (for fuzzing, not an API, but we want to do some of the same stuff). The way I handled this was by manually reading imports in the root schema, and loading them myself, then storing the structs and enums by ID in the same place the types from the root schema are stored. See this section of my project: https://github.com/0bs3n/capnp_generator/blob/5eeb80b224982d654e77accc12324d57df2e093d/capnp_generator/node.py#L78 Hope that helps

Thanks. I figured out that solution in the meantime, too. Works well.
